# Compiling driver for RNX-MiniN2 on kernel 3.X

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to compile an open source driver for my new USB Rosewill RNX-MiniN2 wireless adapter, and I'm running into the following error:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.0.0-14-generic/build M=/home/rfkrocktk/Desktop/RTL8192CU_8188CUS_8188CE-VAU_linux_v3.1.2590.20110922/driver/rtl8192_8188CU_linux_v3.1.2590.20110922  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-14-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/rfkrocktk/Desktop/RTL8192CU_8188CUS_8188CE-VAU_linux_v3.1.2590.20110922/driver/rtl8192_8188CU_linux_v3.1.2590.20110922/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/rfkrocktk/Desktop/RTL8192CU_8188CUS_8188CE-VAU_linux_v3.1.2590.20110922/driver/rtl8192_8188CU_linux_v3.1.2590.20110922/core/rtw_cmd.c:24:0:
/home/rfkrocktk/Desktop/RTL8192CU_8188CUS_8188CE-VAU_linux_v3.1.2590.20110922/driver/rtl8192_8188CU_linux_v3.1.2590.20110922/include/osdep_service.h:49:29: fatal error: linux/smp_lock.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/home/rfkrocktk/Desktop/RTL8192CU_8188CUS_8188CE-VAU_linux_v3.1.2590.20110922/driver/rtl8192_8188CU_linux_v3.1.2590.20110922/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/rfkrocktk/Desktop/RTL8192CU_8188CUS_8188CE-VAU_linux_v3.1.2590.20110922/driver/rtl8192_8188CU_linux_v3.1.2590.20110922] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-14-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
Compile make driver error: 2, Please check error Mesg
```

Evidently, due to recent kernel changes, `smp_lock.h` doesn't exist anymore.

How can I kludge this together and make it work? I just paid for this USB stick and I'd like to be able to use it and not have to ship it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to create a fake `smp_lock.h` file in `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/`:

```
sudo touch "/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/smp_lock.h
```

It works!